# customize a theme in magento 2.2.6

Tags: theme, magento2.2.6

I am trying to customize a theme in Magento but it does not work.
I added my own stylesheet instead of the old one print.css and changed the default-head-blocks.xml and deployed setup Magento and flush all caches but nothing changes, how can I customize my theme, any advice, please?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the css in your theme using **_extend.less** file.

Create `app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/web/css/source/_extend.less`

and add your css there.

Run deploy command.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Answer (score 0):

1) First you need to override print.less from the blank theme.

```
**vendor\magento\theme-frontend-blank\web\css\print.less
copy this file and override in your theme directory.**
```

2) **dev\tools\grunt\configs\theme.js** 
open this file and add print.less in your theme.

```
yourtheme: {
        area: 'frontend',
        name: 'vendor/yourtheme', 
        locale: 'en_US',
        files: [
            'css/styles-m',
            'css/styles-l',
            'css/print'
        ],
        dsl: 'less'
    },
```

3) Run command php bin/magento c:f

4) Run command php bin/magento s:up

After that you can run grunt exec and grunt watch command then check is print.less is compile or not.

I hop this will help you.